# Limiting thread operations per second

Tags: java, multithreading, limit

I've been working on a game on my own, and I need some help with limiting the operations-per-second of a thread. Is there any bulletproof way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no.  Once a thread is dispatched onto a core, its code is run as fast as its core can manage to, given the usualy contraints of cache misses, memory-bandwidth, page-faults etc.

If you want to slow up its overall operation, you are going to have to make it wait on something or sleep, so it gets blocked.